# How to remove records with blank values based on existence in specific column? - SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, exists, sql-null

I want to remove all records with blank values in `prev` and `next` - but only for cases where the `curr` value still exists elsewhere. For example,

Input:

```
prev   curr   next   rand_value
       B             1231
       B             323
A      B             3232
       B      C      3233
       D             12313
```

Output:

```
prev   curr   next   rand_value
A      B             3232
       B      C      3233
       D             12313
```

My code so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE prev IS NOT NULL
OR next IS NOT NULL
-- but this doesn't catch the final row
-- maybe use something like EXISTS?
```

Comment: Have you tried exists?

Comment: I have but I'm confused about how it would work to get my output

Comment: could assign a row number to each (partition by rand_value order by prev, next, curr) and then limit to RN = 1.  Not sure if

Comment: What do you want to happen to records where prev or next is null but the other is not?

Comment: I still want to keep the records where either prev or next is null. Only when both prev and next are null, we can remove them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.prev IS NOT NULL 
   OR t1.next IS NOT NULL
   OR NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tablename t2
        WHERE t2.curr = t1.curr AND (t2.prev IS NOT NULL OR t2.next IS NOT NULL)
      );
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=039d6425640e545942d344f24c8c0f59).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like this. Since I don't need both `prev` and `next` to be not null, should the first `WHERE` condition also use `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: @RicardoFrancois see my edited answer and the demo.

Answer (score 0):

each unique rand_value will get a row number 1 to X... ordered by prev, next value.  If both are "NULL" it will get a row_number of 1.  Since nulls appear first we have to assign a descending order.

Perhaps 1 way....

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by rand_value order by prev DESC, next DESC) RN
FROM my_table)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN =1
```

Alternative way:  Get all that are not null, then get all nulls union...

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE prev IS NOT NULL
   OR next IS NOT NULL  

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE prev IS NULL
  AND next is NULL
```